# minimize length of string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I want to reduce the length of a string. Like...

This string...

```
string foo ="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in vehicula nulla. Phasellus libero dui, luctus quis bibendum sit amet";
```

Becomes this string...

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You dont really ask any question.

Comment: Obviously you use a combination of Find and Replace but you questions is poorly phrased, it's not clear what's being asked here.

Comment: There should be a "this question should be closed because it is too trivial" option...

Comment: You know, there's a saying "there are no stupid questions"... somehow I wish it didn't apply here but to take the high road means to be patient and understanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string foo ="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in vehicula nulla. Phasellus libero dui, luctus quis bibendum sit amet";

string small_foo = foo.SubString(0, 50);
```

Using Substring to get the first 50 characters of the string.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Comment: Some bounds-checking should be performed here. This will blow up if `foo` is shorter than 50 chars.

Comment: I hoped the OP would figure that out when reading the manual.

Comment: Since he is obviously not familiar with SubString, I would not be to sure. But *now* at least he should be ;)

Comment: Note that this solution also doesn't yield the results that the OP requested - 50 characters of the text plus "..."

Answer (score 3):

Code

```
public string Truncate(string input, int length)
{
    if (input.Length < length) return input;
    int index = input.IndexOf(' ', length);
    return input.Substring(0, index) + "...";
}

...

string foo ="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in vehicula nulla. Phasellus libero dui, luctus quis bibendum sit amet";

string bar = Truncate(foo, 50);
Console.WriteLine(bar);
```

Output

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...

Instead of

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in vehicula nulla. Phasellus libero dui, luctus quis bibendum sit amet

Comment: You should put if (index < 0) return input; before returning the substring

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string myString = ".....";
int maxLength = 30;

if( myString.Length > maxLength ){
  myString = myString.SubString(0, maxLength);
}
```

`myString` is now the maximum of `maxLength`'s size.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string foo = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in vehicula nulla. Phasellus libero dui, luctus quis bibendum sit amet";
        int maxlength = 50;
        string shortFoo = StringShortener(foo, maxlength);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} \n becomes: \n {1}", foo, shortFoo);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static string StringShortener(string foo, int maxlength)
    {
        if (foo.Length <= maxlength)
            return foo;
        else
            return foo.Substring(0, maxlength - 4) + "...";
    }
}
```

Comment: A note on naming. Methods should be actions (i.e. verbs) and objects should be nouns. "StringShortener" sounds like a noun. Perhaps you should call your method "ShortenString" or the more conventional "Truncate".

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static string TruncatString(string input, int maxLength)
        {
            if (input.Length < maxLength) return input;
            return input.Substring(0, maxLength - 3) + "...";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given String -

```
var string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in vehicula nulla. Phasellus libero dui, luctus quis bibendum sit amet";
```

**1. First Scenario**

```
var maxlenght = 15;
var shortString =(string .Length > maxlenght ) ?  string.Substring(0,maxlenght ) + "..." : string;
```

> **Output :** "Lorem ipsum dol...";

**2. Second Scenario**

```
var shortString =(string .Length > maxlenght ) ?  string.Substring(0, string.IndexOf(" ", 15)) + "..." : string;
```

> **Output:** "Lorem ipsum dolor...";

if u want last word full then second senario is best...

this works me fine now...

```
 public static string GetShortTitleForDisplay(string title, int noOfCharacter)
    {
        var shortTitle = title;
        if (title.Length <= noOfCharacter) return shortTitle;
        var pos = title.IndexOf(" ", noOfCharacter, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (pos > 0)
            shortTitle = title.Substring(0, pos) + " ...";
        return shortTitle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string foo ="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in vehiculanulla. Phasellus libero dui, luctus quis bibendum sit amet";
string small_foo = foo.Substring(new  Random().Next(0, urlsafe.Length), new Random().Next(2, 6));
```

Comment: You left off the "..."

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```cs
string longString = "hi, am Ramy, a backend and a frontend developer, am here to
help people in Programming with C#";
int maxLength = 17;
if (longString.Length < maxLength)
{
    longString = longString.Substring(0, 17) + "..."; //Those 3 dots are additional (if you want)
}
```

The result will be : `// hi, am Ramy, a ba...`