# C# - String Replace

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a simple question that I am having trouble trying to find an answer for. I want to create a string that after 50 characters will replace everything after it with three dots? So as a quick example:

(The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog)
would become something like:
(The quick brown fox jumped over the la...)

If someone could give me a quick answer or point me to an answered question that would be much appreciated?

Comment: Have you tried the simplest approach of using `Substring` to get the first 50 characters? What pitfalls did you run into, such as inputs not of the appropriate length, perhaps unfortunate breaking inside words or after punctuation, etc?

Comment: see similar questions on SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=truncate+c%23+string and on the web:
http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=truncate+a+c%23+string

Comment: did you try something as google? it's very hard to believe, you can't find something such simple...

Comment: Well i'm a programming student and i'm just starting out, i had a look online but i guess i was searching the wrong thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [minimize length of string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340077/minimize-length-of-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (text.Length > 50) 
    text = text.Substring(0,50) + "...";
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string shortened = s.Length > 50 ? s.Substring(0, 50) + "..." : s;
```

Might need a bit of tweaking since this one would also replace a single character by the ellipsis which, if you do it for display length purposes is probably not adequate.

Comment: Curses. You saved time by using single character variables.

Comment: Psh, I also rewrote the code to use a conditional expression instead of an `if` statement :-P

Comment: Is it allowed in C# to use reserved keywords as variable names?

Comment: I beat you by mere seconds, my friend.

Comment: maybe you can write @short... short is reserved

Answer (score 3):

Use substring: `(yourstringvariable.Length > 50 ? yourstringvariable.Substring(0, 50) + "..." : yourstringvariable);`

Answer (score 2):

It also might be nice to implement this as an extension method. Like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Truncate(this String str, int length)
    {
        return str.Substring(0, length) + "...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My assumption here is that you want at most maxLength characters.

```
if(string.Length >= maxLength)  
{   
    string newString = string.Substring(0, maxLength - 3);  
    newString += "...";  
}
```

Comment: That would leave 47 characters instead. He just wants three dots after 50 characters, unless of course maxLength == 53. :)

Comment: `string.length()` What C# dialect are you using? ;-)

Comment: @drw there is a note at the top of my answer about maxLength.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
string mystring;
myString = (orig_string.Length > 50) ? orig_string.SubString(0, 50) + "..." : orig_string;
```